# Heroku app throws "Internal Server Error"

Tags: ruby, deployment, heroku, padrino

This app works just fine on my local computer. After pushing it to Heroku, static pages appear to be working but the blog section throws an Internal Server Error. I pulled the logs by running "heroku logs" and this is what I get:

```
==> production.log <==
 /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
 /home/slugs/215194_e5b887e_c999/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
 /home/slugs/215194_e5b887e_c999/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'
 /home/slugs/215194_e5b887e_c999/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
 /home/slugs/215194_e5b887e_c999/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `send'
 /home/slugs/215194_e5b887e_c999/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
 /home/slugs/215194_e5b887e_c999/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
 /home/slugs/215194_e5b887e_c999/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/thin-1.2.7/bin/thin:6
```

Something wrong with the eventmachine gem, I suppose....but it works fine on my machine. So I'm not sure what's going on or how to debug it.

Comment: Was an exception thrown? (Looks like a stack trace with the exception message cut out.)

Comment: Could this be it: 
SQLite3::CantOpenException - unable to open database file:
 /disk1/home/slugs/215194_38708ba_c999/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `initialize'

Comment: This is the link to the almost complete error log: http://gist.github.com/443709

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error log, it looks like you are somehow trying to access a database with SQLite3. Heroku's uses Postgresql though, so clearly your database will fail to open. Heroku [generates automatically](http://docs.heroku.com/database) the `database.yml` file, so the error is can't be there but maybe you are requiring and using sqlite3 directly?

Comment: Also, heroku doesn't let you do file operations, so that is another reason why sqlite3 will fail to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how heroku handles things, but the trace/logs seem to say you might not have migrated your database. Is this the case?

Comment: I'm going to take a stab that this is the problem. Did you `heroku rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the heroku gem. Worked for me.